# Is it a good idea to force stop apps after using them?

Tags: security, custom-roms, malware, customization, application-manager

I find myself using **force stop** for every application once I have finished using them. Is this a good practice? Are there any performance or security benefits of doing this? Is force stopping an app necessary to get it out of RAM?

Comment: Well I do have a similar habit as you, but mostly for battery life and peace of mind (screw the constant notifications) instead of RAM. IMO, forcing them out of RAM, especially out of "cached" (not "running") state will increase loading power consumption / time. I use most apps very sparingly so I wouldn't care, though.

Answer (score 25):

**TL;DR:**

No, it's not a good or advisable idea.

**Explanation and some background:**

Force-stopping apps is not intended for "routine use", but for "emergency purposes" (eg. if an app runs out of control and cannot be stopped otherwise, or if an issue causes you to clear cache and delete data from a misbehaving app). Generally spoken, it's neither a "performance booster" nor a "RAM optimizer".

In many cases it won't save battery life either, but rather deplete the battery even faster. Apps don't only start when you tap their icon, they can also get started via intents or broadcasts (eg. on battery low, network changed, USB device connected – but also on many more). So when you "force-stopped" it, on its next start it will have to do a "full init" (loading from the storage(s) and the network) instead of just going back to its "last state" still stored in RAM (unless the system had to clear it out – see our [oom-priority tag-wiki](/tags/oom-priority/info) for details on that process) – what Andy described as "will increase loading power consumption / time" in his comment on your question.

Comment: Would this also apply to iOS? Or should that be asked as a separate question on [apple.se]?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Definitely a separate question.

Comment: I would also add that users who want to make sure they close out of an activity/app completely should use the back button instead of the home button, as using the home button may leave it running in the background for multitasking purposes.

Comment: @oldmud0: Not "Running", it gets stopped. But it remains, yes.

Comment: Some apps misbehave on a pretty regular basis - for example, the official youtube clients, some messengers. Is it possible that they keep doing some faulty crap in the background, depleting the battery? I have a strong (albeit not backed up by any statistics) feeling that they do...

Comment: @Headcrab that's a separate question. But in the context of this one here: yes, a valid reason for a force-stop (until the issue is fixed by the corresponding devs).

Comment: What about if you set Background Process Limit in Developer Options?

Comment: @BamsBamx different question, but IMHO same effect: it's "hidden" there for a reason (and not exposed to the "average Joe"). I'd keep my fingers off it unless you know exactly what you're doing and why.

Comment: @Izzy Why, it is quite relevant in the context of this question. In a better world you may not have to force-stop anything, ever. We live in the real world, though, and not everything works exactly as envisioned by Android architects. Some apps have those issues. You still need to use them. They never get fixed. So, yes, force-stopping an app is not such a bad idea, occasionally.

Comment: @Headcrab isn't that what I wrote? Force-stopping is for curing trouble with a misbehaving app. But you shouldn't do it with all apps everytime you've used them (ie. even without misbehaviour of the app – iow, if your Youtube app misbehaves, why force-stop your mail client?). That was what OP asked for. If FS were a generally bad idea under any circumstances, it wouldn't be there in the first place :)